# While Not doc Is Nothing and doc save

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

Why when doc save ,this code just run once doc,help me fix it.
Thanks a lot for help

Code:

```
While Not (doc Is Nothing)
            If doc.count(0) = 1 Then
                For l%=1 To 30
                    num$=Trim(CStr(l%))
    
                If Trim(doc.getitemvalue("item"+num$)(0))="" Then Exit For
                
                    i1=Format$(Now,"YYYYMMDD")
                    i2=Format$(Now,"hhmmss")
                    i3=Trim(doc.phone(0))
                    i4=Trim(doc.getitemvalue("item"+num$)(0))
                    print i1+i2+i3+i4
                
            Next    
            End If
            doc.count = 2
            doc.Save( True, True )
            Set doc=v.getnextdocument(doc)
        Wend
```

Print:

```
2022102433phone1item1
2022102433phone1item2
2022102433phone1item3
```

Code:

```
While Not (doc Is Nothing)
        If doc.count(0) = 1 Then
            For l%=1 To 30
                num$=Trim(CStr(l%))

            If Trim(doc.getitemvalue("item"+num$)(0))="" Then Exit For
            
                    i1=Format$(Now,"YYYYMMDD")
                    i2=Format$(Now,"hhmmss")
                    i3=Trim(doc.phone(0))
                    i4=Trim(doc.getitemvalue("item"+num$)(0))
                    print i1+i2+i3+i4
            
        Next    
        End If
        Set doc=v.getnextdocument(doc)
    Wend
```

Print:

```
2022102433phone1item1
2022102433phone1item2
2022102433phone1item3
2022102433phone2item1
2022102433phone2item2
2022102433phone2item3
2022102433phone3item1
2022102433phone3item2
2022102433phone3item3
```

Comment: As it stands, it looks as though that code will not run: there should be an "End If" after the "Exit For" as a minimum.

Comment: @RobMason When you put a single statement on the same line as the 'if.. then', you don't need an 'end if'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the view selection formula.  Does it depend on the field `CCount`.  If the save changes values on the document, the document may be removed from the view.  If this is the case, change the code to:

```
Dim doc2 As NotesDocument

While Not (doc Is Nothing)
    If doc.count(0) = 1 Then
        For l%=1 To 30
            num$=Trim(CStr(l%))
            
            If Trim(doc.getitemvalue("item"+num$)(0))="" Then 
                Exit For
            End If
            
            i1=Format$(Now,"YYYYMMDD")
            i2=Format$(Now,"hhmmss")
            i3=Trim(doc.phone(0))
            i4=Trim(doc.getitemvalue("item"+num$)(0))
            Print i1+i2+i3+i4
            
        Next    
    End If
    doc.ccount = 2
    Set doc2 = v.getnextDocument(doc)
    Call doc.Save( True, True )
    Set doc=doc2
Wend
```

Comment: Or use v.AutoUpdate= False... Question: is it doc.count or doc.ccount, or are both correct in the code?

Comment: Sorry,all is doc.count